# Trouble with $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .post

I am trying to insert some values into an sql database.

I am using

```
<input type="text" name="message" id="message"  />
<input type="image" src="boca.png" onClick="send();" />
```

to get the value
and

```
function send(){

var mess = $('#message').val('');   
var dataString = 'message:'+ mess;  
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "atuamae.org/send.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
    $('#message').val('');
  }  
});  }
```

to send it to the php file
and in the php file:

```
$message = $_GET['message'];
```

I think the error occurs either in sending or in the way the  var dataString is encoded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply enough, you're using the HTTP POST method, not the HTTP GET method, so you need to use `$_POST` rather than `$_GET` on the PHP side.

Comment: Also, data expects either a query string (name=value&name2=value2&...) or an object, so you might want to replace dataString with { message: mess }.

Comment: The way you use the verbs in your answer may actually point to a source of confusion. The OP is actually trying to _get_ the variables on the PHP side, but not `GET` the variables. Just an observation that hadn't occured to me before.

Comment: Yeah, good point, it's just what I'm used to in web dev circles. I'll reword :)

Comment: I'm used to that too, but now that you made me think about it, I wonder why they chose those verbs to begin with. Oh well. +1 :)

Comment: Yeah. I'm assuming because `GET` is on the URL query string, so the data isn't really sent, it's more part of the request. article.php?no=5 basically says "GET article 5". `POST` on the other hand is more suited to transmit data, so you end up POSTing some data to the server. Of course, you could fire the data for this on the query string, but that would be...wrong.

Comment: Excellent point slugonamission. I have to go refresh myself on REST. :p

Answer (score 2):

If you are using post you must use $_POST['message'] not $_GET['message']

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the content of the '#message' element

Change

```
var mess = $('#message').val('');
```

to

```
var mess = $('#message').val();
```

And also, yes you are using `POST` but trying to retreive the value through `GET`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var mess  =   document.getElementById('message').value;
var dataString = 'message='+ mess;
```